# Multiple file upload directives and one submit button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have multiple categories of file upload and the HTML given to me has these different categories and each having a file upload control for multiple files. All these sections(and hence the file upload for each sections) are shown in a single HTML. I created a file upload directive and I am using it for each upload section. This works and can handle a button called "Upload" click event and this button is a part of directive.

Now, there is a single button called "Upload All" on click of which I have to update all the files belonging to different sections at one go. So I have to upload files from all the directives on click of this button. How can i have this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there are better ways of doing this but you could try:

Passing a value from the controller to all directives and then on each directive attach a `$watch` on that value. Then clicking the Upload All button would change the value, triggering all the directives to run.

Controller:

```
app.controller = function('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.uploadAllFlag = false;

  $scope.uploadAll = function() {
    $scope.uploadAllFlag = !$scope.uploadAllFlag;
  }
});
```

Directive:

```
app.directive = function('directive', function() {
 return {
   scope: { flag: '=' }
   link: function(scope) {
      scope.$watch('flag', function(){
         //do your upload stuff
      }
   }
});
```

Or alternativelly, inject the $rootScope on your controller and broadcast an event which you could catch on the directives:

```
app.controller = function('Ctrl', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  $scope.uploadAll = function(){
    $rootScope.$broadcast('uploadAll');
  };
});

app.directive = function('directive', function(){
 link: function(scope) {
   scope.$on('uploadAll', function(){
     //do something
   }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple jsfiddle. The main idea is included there: http://jsfiddle.net/VpmV2/45/

```
[1]http://jsfiddle.net/VpmV2/45/
```